# Ncover returns error #20000

Tags: .net, gallio, ncover

I am executing **Ncover.Console.exe** with **gallio.echo** in the following manner

> Ncover.Console.exe //pm Gallio.Host.exe

But Ncover returns **error #20000 " no data collected"**.

gallio version 3.4
Ncover complete trial version : 3.4

Please suggest.

Comment: what type of coverage ( code coverage /unit test coverage ) you want?

Comment: Yeah currently I m able to solve the issue by installing ncover 3 and executing it by passing it as an argument to gallio.echo.exe like /runner:Ncover3 <assembly> //at Ncover3.trend .

Comment: good, add it as an answer so others can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the issue by installing `ncover 3` and executing it by passing it as an argument to `gallio.echo.exe` like

`/runner:Ncover3 <assembly> //at Ncover3.trend` .